# xcode autolayout hidden view takes up space

Tags: xcode, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have been struggling all day to make this work but
but without success. I tried to set the Button Top Constraing (Vertical spacing)
relative to the tableView.
But when I hide the tableview from my swift code the tableview
still takes up space.

[image: layout views]

What I am trying to achieve is that when I hide the tableview it will
no longer take up space and all above views in this case the button will
be moved up like so:

[image]

I have also tried this:
Set UIsearchbox top constraint then Set tableview top constraint
and then set Button top constraint relative to tableview
then created top constrait of Button relative
to Uisearchbox with a priority of 250.
But it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visibility of views has no effect on constraints. Hidden views still participate in the constraint system just like visible ones.

If you want the layout to change when a view's visibility changes, you have to modify the constraints manually when your view's visibility changes. You can either disable/uninstall some and enable/install others, or possibly change the constant of a constraint.

One way to do it is similar to what you tried. Create a constraint that the button's top must be greater than or equal to the table view's bottom. Create another constraint that the button's top is equal to the search box's bottom, with a somewhat reduced priority (but still fairly high, say 900).

There are infinitely many positions for the button that satisfy the first constraint because it's an inequality. The second constraint can't be satisfied as such, but that's OK because it's a lower priority. Still, the auto layout system tries to get as close as possible to satisfying it. That resolves the ambiguity and keeps the button right up against the bottom of the table view.

Keep an outlet to the first constraint. When you hide the table view, subtract a large value from the `constant` of the first constraint. You don't have to pick the value with care, just so long as it's sure to be larger than the height of the table view. Let's say 10,000. The second constraint was trying to pull the button up to just below the search box. The first constraint was preventing that, but this change in the constant relieves that limitation and allows the second constraint to be directly satisfied by moving the button up.

When you show the table view, add the large value back to the constant, returning it to its original value.

Comment: Hello Ken,
The exact thing I did was:
1 Add top constrant of button relative to tableview
2 Add top constraint of button relative to uisearchbox with priority 900
3 The top constraint of button relative to tableview I set to be greater or equal than tableview bottom
4 I add an outlet for the constraint relative to tableview and when
I hide the tableview I change the constant to
self.buttonTopTableviewConstr.constant = -10000

I didnt set any width/height or equal width/height or other horizontal constraints. Just the 4 things I mentioned.

It doesnt work
Am I missing something?
Thank you!!!

Comment: By "doesn't work" you mean the button doesn't move up to be just below the search box? Are you sure you connected the outlet? Try logging the result of `[theButton constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical]` after changing the constant.

Comment: Can you help how to make that call in swift? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure. I imagine it's `println(button.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(Vertical))` assuming you have an outlet for the button.

Comment: Thanks, I printed
button.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Vertical)
And here is the output:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sJdFBb7E

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong, but it's saying that you have **no** explicitly created constraints on that view. There are only ones created automatically during build because you haven't created any. Could you be modifying a completely different NIB/storyboard than you're testing with? Or did you log the constraints from a different button? Edit your question to show all of the constraints in your NIB/storyboard. Also, if IB is showing that there is ambiguity in your layout, be sure to fix that. You might do Add Missing Constraints, although you'll then want to review what it adds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70974/discussion-between-bornie-and-ken-thomases).

Comment: You have set up the specific constraints that I mentioned correctly. However, I did not mean to imply that those were the only constraints you have in the whole view. IB is showing that you have errors. In the document outline, at the top, there's a red arrow. Click it and it will show the errors. For example, there's nothing pinning the search box to the top of its superview. Similarly, there's nothing pinning the table view to the search box. During build, constraints are being added to compensate for these ambiguities. Those added constraints are defeating the scheme to move the label.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I'm new and coming from android these constraints seem too much trouble for me at the moment. 
Have a wonderful day.